# How to encode full range video on Android with MediaCodec when using surface input?

Tags: android, c++, android-mediacodec, surface

I'm trying to encode bt709 full range video with MediaCodec. When using surface as input, setting the COLOR_RANGE property in MediaFormat causes strange behavior on Qualcomm phones, encoded videos seem to be white washed out(maybe RGBA transformed with wrong matrix). Any idea of what should I do to ensure the rgba2yuv transform is correct? I'm using native c++ code and using JNI to call Java methods.

Also, I've tried to using buffer as input, however, since I need to get render result from video editing, glReadPixels causes terrible delay. Even after I use shader to convert RGBA to yuv and use PBO to get data, encoding with buffers are still terribly slow, about double time as surface input, which is almost not useable for my scenario.

Comment: Just find out an interesting thing, with Qualcomm SOCs, the SDR BT709 limited range conversion is also using a wrong matrix(seems like BT601 tv). I've tested different phones, those with Kirin SOCs and MTK SOCs produce correct BT709 tv videos, and all devices with Qualcomm SOCs produce videos which have color shifts with original videos.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `COLOR_RANGE_FULL` for video encoding with the `MediaCodec`, use `COLOR_RANGE_LIMITED`.

The "limited" color range is the default for video content.
When the video encoder converts RGB color values to YCbCr it converts them to the limited range according to the `BT.709` standard. The color range property used to configure the encoder has no effect on the conversion.

But why is the video washed out?

If you use the same `MediaFormat` to configure both the `MediaCodec` and the `MediaMuxer` then the output file will incorrectly contain the "full" color range in the metadata. The decoder / player will see the "full" range and
misinterpret the color values.

Comment: However I need to encode full range YUV video, i.e, 0-255. This default limited range conversion is definitely not what i expected(since I failed to convince my boss... ). These encoded videos' metadata are set to full range(yuvj420p from ffprobe) but the color is incorrect.

Comment: When using Huawei P40 pro with Harmony OS, the yuv value of encoded videos are correctly converted to full range, although the encode speed is as slow as avcodec. Seems the OEMs are responsible for the implementation.

Comment: Hardware codecs are implemented by GPU manufacturers and I am afraid the support of the full range is not required by the SDR standards. And software codecs is much slower.

Comment: You might find this information useful: https://video.stackexchange.com/a/22135

Comment: i've posted an answer something i think u would like to know